# Oracle Please look into PDB_PLUG_IN_VIOLATIONS view for more details

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle19c, pluggable-database

When creating a PDB in an Oracle 19.16 database, I get a warning in the logs:

```
TEST_DB(4):WARNING: Pluggable Database TEST_DB with pdb id - 4 is
TEST_DB(4):         altered with errors or warnings. Please look into
TEST_DB(4):         PDB_PLUG_IN_VIOLATIONS view for more details.
```

As a result of the select * from PDB_PLUG_IN_VIOLATIONS query, I get:

```
OPTION  WARNING 0   1   Database option JAVAVM mismatch: PDB installed version NULL. CDB installed version 19.0.0.0.0.  RESOLVED    Fix the database option in the PDB or the CDB   7
OPTION  WARNING 0   1   Database option JAVAVM mismatch: PDB installed version NULL. CDB installed version 19.0.0.0.0.  PENDING Fix the database option in the PDB or the CDB   2
OPTION  WARNING 0   1   Database option JAVAVM mismatch: PDB installed version NULL. CDB installed version 19.0.0.0.0.  PENDING Fix the database option in the PDB or the CDB   5
OPTION  WARNING 0   1   Database option JAVAVM mismatch: PDB installed version NULL. CDB installed version 19.0.0.0.0.  PENDING Fix the database option in the PDB or the CDB   3
OPTION  WARNING 0   1   Database option JAVAVM mismatch: PDB installed version NULL. CDB installed version 19.0.0.0.0.  PENDING Fix the database option in the PDB or the CDB   6
OPTION  ERROR   0   2   Database option CATJAVA mismatch: PDB installed version 19.0.0.0.0. CDB installed version NULL. PENDING Fix the database option in the PDB or the CDB   7
OPTION  ERROR   0   3   Database option XML mismatch: PDB installed version 19.0.0.0.0. CDB installed version NULL. PENDING Fix the database option in the PDB or the CDB   7
OPTION  WARNING 0   1   Database option JAVAVM mismatch: PDB installed version NULL. CDB installed version 19.0.0.0.0.  PENDING Fix the database option in the PDB or the CDB   4
```

I did not find an answer to the question of what to do with this warning. On the СDB, JavaVM, XML options are really active.

Tell me how to remove these warnings? (Should I pay attention to them?).

I do not need the specified options on all  pluggable databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per MOS note 2020172.1

*It is okay for a PDB to have a subset (fewer) options installed than the CDB into which it is plugged*

for which you still get a WARNING message in PDB_PLUG_IN_VIOLATIONS, but its OK to ignore it.

However, ERROR entries are different, because that looks like you have options installed in the PDB that are not present in the CDB. You'd need to install those options in the CDB to get these resolved.